# Xcode 6.2 beta 2 WKInterfaceController watchkit error

Tags: xcode, swift, watchkit

This code:

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var petTable: WKInterfaceTable!

var petnames = ["Luna", "dylan", "Mery", "Mady", "Paul Newman", "heidi"]

override init(context: AnyObject?) {
    // Initialize variables here.
    super.init(context: context)
```

return two errors:
" Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass" in the line override

" Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'WKInterfaceController'" in the line super.init

the error is in Xcode 6.2 beta 2 (launch today)

In the previous version of Xcode no errors show

Answer (score 6):

Replace

```
override init(context: AnyObject?) {
    // Initialize variables here.
    super.init(context: context)

    // Configure interface objects here.


    NSLog("%@ init", self)

}
```

with

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    // Configure interface objects here.
    NSLog("%@ awakeWithContext", self)
}
```

Clean your project then build and run

Answer (score 1):

`init(context: AnyObject?)` does not exist anymore.  For initialization just use `init` and then use `awakeWithContext` to initialize from context.

Comment: I would ask questions about beta releases like this on the Apple Developer Forums as they are NDA safe.

Comment: The WatchKit APIs and documentation are publicly available.  You don't need to sign in with an Apple dev account that has accepted the NDA to read the API docs.

Comment: Ahh! I hadn't realized that the documentation was available without a login. It's the downloads of the SDK and tools that requires an account. Thanks.